# POSIX way to add content around a line in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, posix, ed

I'm looking for a way to edit files with a script that will provide an alternate definition for a variable in C and this redefinition is controlled by a compiler D-flag using a POSIX application that I write a script for. So for example, imagine the token `nice_var` should be renamed to `cool_var` like so:

Sample input:

```
struct BigThing nice_var;

/* some lines later */

    nice_var->thing = 1;
```

Expected output:

```
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
struct BigThing cool_var;
#else
struct BigThing nice_var;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */

/* some lines later */

/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
    cool_var->thing = 1;
#else
    nice_var->thing = 1;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */
```

Every occurrence of the string should be encapsulated in the preprocessor directive pattern shown, even if the usages occur on consecutive lines.

Yeah I could write a python/perl/javascript script to do this, but is there a POSIX application that can support this kind of file editing? I've expected `ed` or `ex` to be able to do this, but I can't figure out how to loop in `ed` to address all occurrences in a file nor how to get `ex` to detect when the search has reached the end of the file. Info on how to detect that in `ex` may be all I need to meet my goal.

If it isn't obvious, I plan to use the script, which I will call `renamer`, to edit all the files
with occurrences of 'nice_var' in a workspace, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux
for file in $(grep --files-with-matches --recursive 'nice_var'); do
    renamer --feature-name RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED --var-name 'nice_var' --replacement 'cool_var' "${file}"
done
```

No need to handle the command line arguments in the answers. I'm more interested in the concepts of adding content before a line that matches, and copying the line.

The question really boils down to, "Is there a POSIX application that supports repeated searching for a pattern, then adding lines before and after the line where the pattern has been found, where one of the added lines matches the line with the pattern except the pattern has been replaced?"

Maybe `awk` with multiple passes?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by POSIX tool here. Does it need to be a tool that is defined in the POSIX specs and, by extension, any solution using that tool should restrict itself to the POSIX implementation of said tool (so awk, not gawk and sed not GNU sed etc)? Or do you want something specifically designed for this? Should we provide scripting answers? In tools like perl or python as you mentioned or are those ruled out because they don't have a POSIX definition?

Comment: Defined in the POSIX specs and restricted to the POSIX implementation. Is there something specifically designed for this? Sure, I'll take it.

Scripting answers, using a POSIX script. `awk`, `ed`, and `ex` can be scripted. `/bin/sh` invoking `sed` would be appropriate too.

Comment: You can't do this robustly without writing a parser for `C` so - are you OK with a "best effort" solution?

Comment: Ed, yeah, best effort. Assume the variable names don't clash with the language's special strings. Regex should be able to handle word boundaries, but at the end of the day, the user of the script must inspect the diff before committing. The changes all go through review. I don't accept the idea that a C parser is needed to do this properly. I'll be entertained by your justification as attempts to convince me.

Comment: Just a tiny comment on the shell script snippet that you include: Note that "long options" can not be parsed by POSIX `getopts` in a shell script, and that neither `--files-with-matches` nor `--recursive` are POSIX options to the `grep` utility.

Comment: For that matter, `bash` isn't POSIX either. If you want to keep things POSIX, use `/bin/sh` which, if your `/bin/sh` is `bash`, will at least run `bash` in its POSIX mode and whould otherwise be an actual POSIX shell.

Comment: Ah, right my mistake on making a bash script that isn't POSIX complaint. I used the long options so that it was obvious what the arguments did in the requested script.

Comment: If you want to be picky, the `#!`-line in scripts isn't fully POSIX either (a strictly conforming application [is not allowed to start with the two characters `#!`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html)), so you better use an explicit interpreter on the command line when running the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "best effort" solution that provides a naïve substitution without awareness of language syntax, regardless of whether the text is a variable, in a comment line (`/* don't change nice_var here */`), quoted in a string (`char *p = "I've got nice_var here"`), or even part of another word (`int quitenice_vartoo`). You'd want an approximation to a C language parser to get this properly correct.

```
awk -v src=nice_var -v dst=cool_var -v macro=RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED '
    $0 ~ src {
        this = that = $0;
        gsub(src, dst, that);
        printf "/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */\n#ifdef %s\n%s\n#else\n%s\n#endif /* %s */\n", macro, that, this, macro;
        next
    }
    1
' sourcefile.c
```

Output from your example:

```
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
struct BigThing cool_var;
#else
struct BigThing nice_var;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */

/* some lines later */

/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
    cool_var->thing = 1;
#else
    nice_var->thing = 1;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */
```

Notice that `src` is actually a Regular Expression used by `awk` to match for the replacement text. My example is a string literal but it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: The awk solution looks like it could be extended with more functionality more easily, so I am accepting it as the answer. Thanks for showing me how it could be done in a single pass.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
/nice_var/!b
h
i\
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */\
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
s//cool_var/gp
i\
#else
g
a\
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */
```

Ignore lines not matching `nice_var` (branch to the end of the script for each such line).  For a line matching `nice_var`, store the line in the hold space with `h`, insert the "prefix" (`#ifdef ...`), change `nice_var` to `cool_var` and print the modified line, insert the "infix" (`#else`), fetch the original line from the hold space with `g` (this doesn't actually print it, the implicit print does that at the end), and append the "suffix" (`#endif`).

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file.c
struct BigThing nice_var;

/* some lines later */

    nice_var->thing = 1;
```

```bash
$ sed -f script file.c
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
struct BigThing cool_var;
#else
struct BigThing nice_var;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */

/* some lines later */

/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED
    cool_var->thing = 1;
#else
    nice_var->thing = 1;
#endif /* RENAME_FEATURE_ENABLED */
```

To parametrize the `sed` script, use a here-document.  Note that this requires that the first argument is a POSIX basic regular expression that is suitable for use as the pattern in a `sed` substitution, and that the second argument is a text string that is suitable in the replacement part of the substitution command.  The third argument must be a valid C preprocessor macro name.

```bash
src=$1
dst=$2
mac=$3

cat >script <<SED_SCRIPT
/$src/!b
h
i\\
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */\\
#ifdef $mac
s//$dst/gp
i\\
#else
g
a\\
#endif /* $mac */
SED_SCRIPT

sed -f script
```

Testing:

```bash
$ sh replacer nice cool HELLO <file.c
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef HELLO
struct BigThing cool_var;
#else
struct BigThing nice_var;
#endif /* HELLO */

/* some lines later */

/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef HELLO
    cool_var->thing = 1;
#else
    nice_var->thing = 1;
#endif /* HELLO */
```

```bash
$ sh replacer 'nice_\(var\)' '\1iable' HELLO <file.c
/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef HELLO
struct BigThing variable;
#else
struct BigThing nice_var;
#endif /* HELLO */

/* some lines later */

/* TODO temporary ifdef to facilitate renaming */
#ifdef HELLO
    variable->thing = 1;
#else
    nice_var->thing = 1;
#endif /* HELLO */
```